# Send date from JavaScript to PHP without using Query String

Tags: javascript, php

Is there any easy way to pass data from JavaScript to PHP without using the Query String Method.

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="getlat" name="getlat" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['polat']; ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="getlon" name="getlon" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['polon']; ?>" />
```

PHP Code

```
$lat = '-27.486204'; // Should get latitude from JS here.
$long = '152.994962'; // Should get longitude from JS here.

    mysqli_query("SELECT * From `table_nme` where `latitude`='.$lat.' AND `longitude`='.$long.'");
```

I know how to do this in Query String Process but I need it without Query String Process.

Comment: Simple answer: `Ajax`.

Comment: There's a few options, but what's wrong with a query string? Do you have some particular limitation that might indicate what option is best for your situation? Also, the current method for building your SQL query is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you support client data and simply insert it into the SQL.

Comment: One simple option is to use cookies. (probably not the best option)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ajax (jquery)* to send your data to server.

*JS*

```
$.ajax({url:"yourfile.php",type:"POST",async:false,
   data:{getlat:$("#getlat").val(),getlon:$("#getlon").val()}
});
```

*PHP*

```
$lat = $_POST["getlat"];
$lon = $_POST["getlon"];
...
```

Another solution is to use cookies. Personally i use [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to get/set my cookies:

*JS*

```
....
$.cookie("data",{getlat:$("#getlat").val(),getlon:$("#getlon").val()});
```

*PHP*

```
$data = json_decode($_COOKIE["data"]);
$lat = $data["getlat"];
$lon = $data["getlon"];
...
```